# How does one handle program state logic?

Tags: java, client-server, client-side, server-side

I'm writing a client-server program in java.

The basis is that the program presents eulas and options to the user and the user responds accordingly, moving through menus until he can get the server to provide the client with the requested item. For example, a document or file.

My question is where should I handle the state of each individual client. Should each client maintain it's own state, should the server create threads to maintain the state of each of it's client, or is there an even better approach?

What would be the simplest and/or most efficient method of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assign each client an ID (for instance, a session ID) and track the state on the server. This would make it harder, I think, to game the system (under the principle that the less sensitive info there is on the client side, the better.)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of client/server protocol are you using? If you're using HTTP, you could use the built-in session capability provided by Java Servlets (assuming you're using those, too.)

Here's a tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html

Comment: It's just a local program, using ServerSockets

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know of anything that provides "sessions" for TCP connections. However, it sounds like you're using a very HTTP-like protocol, (for instance you say the client requests a resource, such as a document or file, and the server replies with it.) If it is possible to switch to HTTP from your current protocol, then you'll have session functionality already implemented for you.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using your own protocol, you may have to do as Ted Hopp suggests, which is to track each client using some sort of ID. This is usually called the "session ID" in web-related contexts. The basic idea, if I'm not mistaken, is that the server generates random, unique IDs, for each client that connects. The client stores this info and sends it to the server with all subsequent communication.

Comment: The server then maintains some sort of data structure that allows it to easily look up the client's state given this session ID.